# Why does NetworkManager ignore config files when SELinux is enabled?

Tags: networkmanager, selinux

I'm trying to set up a system based on AlmaLinux 9.2, to use SELinux and NetworkManager, with a read-only rootfs. For various reasons, I want to keep my 'keyfiles' on a separate partition. I have added a small config file `/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/20-system-connections.conf`, which contains:

```
[keyfile]
path=/data/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/
```

As long as SELinux is 'Permissive' this works very well.

*But*, as soon as I have SELinux 'Enforcing', NetworkManager refuses to read the config file. Looking at `journalctl -u NetworkManager | grep 'Read config'` I see that it doesn't read the config files:

##### SELinux Enforcing:

```
Feb 05 16:34:23 almatest NetworkManager[39809]: <info>  [1707147263.6083] Read config: /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf (run: 15-carrier-timeout.conf)
```

(Note - no `20-system-connections.conf`)

##### SELinux Permissive:

```
Feb 05 16:40:59 almatest NetworkManager[43518]: <info>  [1707147659.1304] Read config: /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf (run: 15-carrier-timeout.conf) (etc: 20-system-connections.conf)
```

(Note - there it is!)

I have set the SELinux context with `semanage fcontext -a -e /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/20-system-connections.conf` - and it shows up as a 'Local fcontext Equivalence' with `semanage fcontext --list`, and

```
# ls -lZ /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/20-system-connections.conf /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root system_u:object_r:NetworkManager_etc_rw_t:s0 2291 Feb  5 16:34 /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root system_u:object_r:NetworkManager_etc_rw_t:s0  275 Feb  5 15:06 /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/20-system-connections.conf
```

This is all based on AlmaLinux 9.2, using `NetworkManager-1.42.2-1.el9.x86_64`.

What am I doing wrong?

I have tried adding

```
[logging]
domains=ALL:TRACE
```

in the `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` - but it doesn't add anything interesting.

Comment: What do the SELinux logs say when the config is being loaded?  What is the SELinux context for the directory `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`?

Comment: > What do the SELinux logs say when the config is being loaded?

That's part of my problem. Where does SELinux put it logs? It seems to be partly in `/var/log/audit/audit.log` and partly in `journalctl --facility=authpriv`. Is there anywhere else to look?

Comment: The contents of `/var/log/audit/audit.log` while you have SELinux problems should suffice.  There should be entries for the denial specifically pointing to why it was denied.

Comment: The problem I had was that some aspects of the SELinux was set to `dontaudit` -- I discovered that it's possible to disable this with `semodule --build --disable_dontaudit`. (`semodule -DB`)

Then I got much more logging to `/var/log/audit/audit.log`  -  some of it relevant to my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer:

It's possible that some SELinux policies are set to `dontaudit` - which means that they will *not* get logged in `/var/log/audit/audit-log`.
It's possible to disable this with `semodule --build --disable_dontaudit`  (`semodule -DB` for short).

That provides much more information in the audit report, some of which was relevant to my issue.